# Issues with NFS share - unable to mount

Tags: linux, networking, grub2, nfs

Ahoy friends. Today i set up my PXE server using dnsmasq as DHCP proxy as well as tftp server. I wanted to set up a grub menu to be able to run Windows ISO files in EFI and Legacy mode, depending on the client. So i set up my grub pxe folder using

> grub-mknetdir

I'm already able to boot into PXEGRUB as well as loading the kernel image of linux distros.
Unfortunately i'm not able to load the initrd files because i'm experiencing some issue regarding my NFS share. Something seems to be wrong there, but i can't find the mistake.

My grub.cfg file which is affected by this problem.

```
   menuentry "Netroot" {
   echo 'Trying to boot via nfs ...'
   load_video
   insmod gzio
   if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
   insmod part_msdos
   insmod ext2
   echo 'Loading Linux ...'
   linux /programs/clonezilla/live/vmlinuz root=/dev/nfs ip=dhcp rw netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.2.55:/var/lib/tftpboot/programs/clonezilla/live/ rw
   echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
   initrd /var/lib/tftpboot/programs/clonezilla/live/initrd.img
}
```

And my file

> /etc/exports

```
# /etc/exports: the access control list for filesystems which may be exported
#       to NFS clients.  See exports(5).
#
# Example for NFSv2 and NFSv3:
# /srv/homes       hostname1(rw,sync,no_subtree_check) hostname2(ro,sync,no_subtree_check)
#
# Example for NFSv4:
# /srv/nfs4        gss/krb5i(rw,sync,fsid=0,crossmnt,no_subtree_check)
# /srv/nfs4/homes  gss/krb5i(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
#

/var/lib/tftpboot/programs/clonezilla/live 192.168.2.55/(rw,no_root_squash,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

So when i try to boot Clonezilla everything is fine, until the step to load the initrd.img file from my nfs share. Something is wrong with it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

So i ran

> cat /var/logs/syslog | grep tftp

and received this output.

```
Oct 21 18:07:29 millenium-fbe48 rpc.mountd[11325]: refused mount request from 192.168.2.86 for /var/lib/tftpboot/programs/clonezilla/live (/var/lib/tftpboot/programs/clonezilla/live): unmatched host
```

So is there something wrong with my nfs share, and what is the problem?

Comment: Your `/etc/exports` share declaration has a host restriction which only allows the host 192.168.2.55, yet in your boot command you specify that same IP address as the NFS server and your client address looks to be 192.168.2.86.  Does your exports file specify the correct host that is allowed to connect to the share?

Comment: In addition to what GracefulRestart said: the 1st screenshot shows that IP address is 192.168.2.85 yet the last error message complains about a mount request from 192.168.2.86. Besides that, there shouldn't be a slash after the IP address and the options.

Comment: Ahoy! Problem solved! https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546605/unable-to-boot-iso-files-from-pxe-grub-menu